# How to use firebase login with expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I was following the instructions on [Expo's docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v12.0.0/guides/using-firebase.html), however I was not sure what goes where. I installed firebase using npm. Then the next step is to copy my firebase setup info, which I did from the firebase console.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "<YOUR-API-KEY>",
  authDomain: "<YOUR-AUTH-DOMAIN>",
  databaseURL: "<YOUR-DATABASE-URL>",
  storageBucket: "<YOUR-STORAGE-BUCKET>"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

But where does this peace of the code go? In root navigation or router? How do I then refer to it in other parts of my app. As you can tell, I'm fairly new to Expo and React-Native, so your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add all these code inside the **main.js** file `componentDidMount()` method. Use the below code for your reference.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const config = {
      apiKey: "<YOUR-API-KEY>",
      authDomain: "<YOUR-AUTH-DOMAIN>",
      databaseURL: "<YOUR-DATABASE-URL>",
      projectId: "<YOUR-PROJECT-ID>",
      storageBucket: "<YOUR-STORAGE-BUCKET>,
      messagingSenderId: "<YOUR-MESSAGING-SENDER-ID>"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View >

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

You have to initialise this once in your **main.js** that is your root file for your project and in the other screen you can import the `firebase` component and work on it.

Comment: thank you. It's so silly that there are so many tutorials on the web that assume beginners know where to put code snippets